# How to save and name a pdf through selenium by providing print keys?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to save a pdf from a website using selenium. I have been able to locate the print element and I'm able to interact with it. However after the print option is clicked on I am not able to save that document. I have tried switching handles as well as tried providing Enter key using ActionChains.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


webdriver_path = "D:/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe"
service = Service(webdriver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.maximize_window()
actions = ActionChains(driver)
url = "https://web.bcpa.net/BcpaClient/#/Record-Search"
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
text_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@class="form-control"]').send_keys("2216 NW 6 PL FORT LAUDERDALE, FL 33311")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
search_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="input-group-addon"]/span[@class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"]').click()
    
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
printer_click = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="col-sm-1  btn-printrecinfo"]').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
all_handles =  driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(all_handles[1])
actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

After hitting the enter I am trying to save the document using address keys provided. Kindly help regarding this.

I tried the above specified code.
Expected document to save in a pdf format.
Code stop working after sending Enter key.

Comment: you might try by using the 'kiosk-printing' option.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72052662/how-to-specify-print-location-for-pdf-printing-with-selenium  You should also be able to access all those options on the right in that print dialog... they'll be in shadow-dom.  If you inspect the dialog, you'll see in "<print-preview-sidebar>" there will be a node called "#shadow-root" there.  (google selenium shadow-dom for how to navigate elements in shadow-dom)